# Find element of class type at scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery

Most questions about CSS positioning tend to ask "what is the position of element X" and I am aware of [How can I tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport) - however I would like to know "what element is at position x"? [Whilst it now appears there is no solution apart from the idea presented in this alt question that you need to test each element, the original question remains different]

I have a scroll window in which I basically want to know which div is no longer visible and which is the first div visible. Is it possible? Is there effectively a selector for `$('div.class atScrollPosition X')` in Jquery or Vanilla JS. Really don't mind.

Comment: A possible dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Comment: No, there is no such selector. You will either have to go and iterate over all relevant elements, and check their position in regard to the viewport - or use an Intersection Observer to determine when elements enter/leave the viewport.

Comment: That is asking if a particular element is visible ... I'm asking what element is visible

Comment: use [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), you can get the visible element by iterating over the entries and check for `entry.isIntersecting`

Comment: @Antony just loop through elements having the desired class name just one extra step.